# Is it possible to get multiple Fanatic/Enthusiast badges?

Tags: support, badges, activity-badges

Can I get multiple Fanatic/Enthusiast badges?

I don't really care if I can or not, I'm just curious... after all we are talking about a colored dot on a computer screen :)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

They're awarded only once. See also [list of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions).

> #### Enthusiast
>
> - silver; **awarded once**; same family as Fanatic (gold)
>
> ...
>
> #### Fanatic
>
> - gold; **awarded once**; same family as Enthusiast (silver)

If a badge can be awarded multiple times, it would be explicitly mentioned like that on the badge page.

Comment: thanks, I knew I had seen that once, but I didn't know where and I couldn't find it again.

Answer (score 4):

Out of those badges that value "doing something repeatedly", [Socratic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/244/socratic) is the only one that gets awarded multiple times.

But of course, you can collect "the same" badge on multiple *different* communities on the stack exchange network. Not really useful, but well, [decide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/299754/which-user-is-the-most-legendary-across-the-whole-network-of-sites) for your own.

Comment: Actually, [getting multiple Fanatic badges is rather easy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296850/295232).

Comment: @Glorfindel I thought so. But there is no point in cheating for badges that can acquired by simple cheating. As we say here in Swabia: "if it costs nothing, it is probably worth nothing".