# Multiple fanatic badges

Tags: feature-request, badges, activity-badges

Yes, I've seen [Is it possible to get multiple Fanatic/Enthusiast badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75078/is-it-possible-to-get-multiple-fanatic-enthusiast-badges)

But what about making it multiple? ;-) Having 100 consecutive visits several times undoubtedly deserves an award.

Comment: Programming a bot that gets the badge for you is perhaps more deserving.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Fanatic is already probably the easiest gold badge you can get -- it's the only one that doesn't require active participation. Being able to earn 3/year while doing nothing devalues the other gold badges that require significant work to achieve

Comment: To get my fanatic badge I took 3g modem and laptop to my christmas trip to not break the chain. Don't agree it was easy :-)))

Comment: @zerkms: I lost hundreds of accumulated days when I went to NZ :(

Comment: @zerkms It's easier than editing 500 posts, or writing a post that gets 100 score. Some people write a script to do it and don't even visit the site

Comment: @Michael Mrozek: then probably it doesn't deserve to be gold initially at all?

Comment: According to [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions) just visiting isn't enough.

Comment: @DaveNewton It is if you visit the right page; visiting the homepage isn't enough, but viewing a question is. My point was it doesn't require you to actually do anything but view a page

Comment: I'd argue that Electorate is the easiest gold badge to get.  While it takes a little more effort than simply visiting the page each day, 600 votes on questions with a 30 vote limit each day would take 20 days to accomplish, and they don't have even be consecutive days.  Truth in reporting, though, I have the Fanatic badge, but not the Electorate.

Comment: xD @zerkms !!! Great!  On Music SE one period I was working hard to get my Fanatic badge, and one day I went out to skiing but then I injured myself and had to end up in the emergency room and THEN I ended up in the hospital - and I broke the badge chain - I was crying - So I got my **Electorate** badge instead - voted 40 times on questions for 15 days (which had no need to be consecutive) - success!

Answer (score 13):

SE-sites are not about you. They are not about me. They are not about get-as-many-badges-as-I-can-doing-nothing-except-visiting-some-website.

They are about our **contribution** to the knowledge base. Although you can honor yourself like @zerkms that you've visited some site 1/3 of the year, the community didn't earn **anything** from this. Not even a simple answer - round zero.

At some sites, Mortarboard is far less easy to get than Fanatic. And instead of just visiting the site you should go to the [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) section and answer some of them. And this will be far more useful.

IMO.