# Earn reputation points when silver and gold badges are earned

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, badges

I think it would be a good idea to gain reputation on silver, and gold badges.

For example, if I gained a gold badge, I would also gain 15 reputation points.

If I gained a silver badge, I would also earn 10 reputation points.

Comment: A bunch of the badges already require implicitly earning a good chunk of reputation before you can even receive them. What is the benefit of giving users a bonus reputation for essentially doing things that earn reputation?

Comment: @animuson we do that all the time in real life. If you earn enough university credits, you can get a degree. If you get enough money, you can invest it.

Comment: Handing out reputation, for earning any badge, is a really bad idea.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Neither of those is really the same situation. You don't earn more university credits because you earned university credits - a degree is a reward for reaching a milestone, similar to receiving a privilege here for earning a certain amount of reputation. But we don't give more reputation for reaching the milestone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/295232) says about reputation:

> It reflects, to an extent, your familiarity with the site, the amount of subject matter expertise you have and the level of respect your peers have for you.

Does [correcting spelling errors in 80 posts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/12/strunk-white) say anything about my subject matter expertise? Or does [visiting the site for 100 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/53/fanatic) say anything about your familiarity with the site, especially when you're essentially [not visiting them at all](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296849/295232)? Yes, there are other badges which indicate an increased level of familiarity with the site, but those usually give you reputation in the process of gaining the badge already. There's no need at all to give an extra bonus; that would just amount to a nearly linear reputation inflation.